Edmonds-Karp shortest-path distance monotonicity

If the Edmonds-Karp algorithm is run on a flow network $G=(V,\ E)$ with source $s$
and sink $t$, then for all vertices $v \in V - \{s,t\} $, the shortest-path distance $\delta_f(s,v)$ in the residual network $G_f$ increases monotonically with each flow augmentation.

Can someone explain the above text from CLRS? At the end of the day, I want to conclude that the total number of critical edges during the entire execution of the Edmonds-Karp algorithm is $O(V \cdot E)$.
Let edge $(u,v)$ be critical edge in augmentation path of distance $d$ so that it gets removed after augmentation (call it $1^{st}$ iteration). Then some other edge in some other path also of distance $d$ gets removed (call it iteration $2^{nd}$). Now, let's say critical edge $(v,u)$ appears in some augmentation path and gets removed (call it iteration $3^{rd}$). Finally, $(u,v)$ again has a chance to reappear but this time the path is of distance at least $d+1$ (call it iteration $4^{th}$)- Why? If not, please explain.

See Lemma 13.3.5 in this lecture note by Sariel Har-Peled for a detailed proof of the above statement.
